# How do I use archive-product as a template on my page template?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is my first ever post on stackoverflow. I have spent days trying to figure this out on my own, searching far and wide anywhere I can, but I am at my wits end and I am about to give up completely.
***Please help me.***

**Task:**

Using a page template (page-sale.php) I need to display all products on sale and be able to sort them by price (asc and desc), by category, and date added.

**Possible solutions:**

Using WP_Query (current situation):

```
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 12,
                    'meta_query' => array( //only get products on sale
                        array(
                            'key'     => '_sale_price',
                            'value'   => 0,
                            'compare' => '>'
                        )
                    )
                );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                    endwhile;
                } else {
                    echo __( 'No products found' );
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
```

This works for displaying products but trying when I want to added a sorting list I also have to do that custom, and I need/want to do it properly - i.e. I don't want to create my own select-option and use $_GET to conditionally change my query, it's just not the clean solution I'm looking for, I know there's a better way.

**My idea:**

Use *wc_get_template_part( 'archive', 'product' )*, or simply copy/paste the archive-product.php contents into my page template, and use WC hooks or edit the template to change the query and sorting list to fit my needs.

So I tried that. Using *wc_get_template_part( 'archive', 'product' )* I tried

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wc_custom_query');
function wc_custom_query() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'meta_query' => array( //only get products on sale
            array(
                'key'     => '_sale_price',
                'value'   => 0,
                'compare' => '>'
            )
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

I also tried *woocommerce_before_shop_loop* and *woocommerce_shop_loop* as hooks.

Additionally I also tried just copying the contents of *archive-product.php* into my page template file, i.e. my *page-sale.php* is a direct copy of *archive-product.php*. But no products show up now, nor does the sortings list, but the Shop page works fine, with the sorting list all products being shown.

**Additional thoughts:**

No, I won't use shortcodes, this needs to be done using a page template.

**Final thoughts:**

I feel so absolutely lost. I have worked with WordPress before but WooCommerce is completely new to me. I have tried to god damned hard to figure this out. But it's like this one step in the documentation is missing, where it explains this on part I don't understand. It's so incredibly frustrating - I am angry and I want to cry.

Even though the documentation is comprehensive, it's just so bad, I have no idea where to look. Everytime I see a question that looks similar to mine it just never fully satisfies my specific needs. The answers I find all make sense and I understand them, I am just missing one piece of the puzzle.

***Please. Help.***

**Update**

So I have done some more testing. Currently I have copied *archive-product.php* to my own template and added my own query, which is working. However, I have discovered that perhaps the reason my sorting list is not showing is because the *before_shop_loop* is not working. I tried solving it from the answer here: [Woocommerce before and after shop loop not works](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277459/woocommerce-before-and-after-shop-loop-not-works), but to no avail. Additionally, I also found [this](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/20169) but it also seems like a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm find this solution:

```
    <?php 

// Display featured products by category. on this case its "shirts" which is the slug of the category.
$query_args = array(
    'featured' => true,  
    'category' => array( 'shirts' ),
);
$products = wc_get_products( $query_args );

global $post;
$columns = wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' );
?>
<div class="woocommerce columns-<?php echo esc_attr( $columns ); ?>">
  <?php
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $post = get_post($product->get_id());
        setup_postdata($post);
        wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
  ?>
</div>
```

So magic in wc_get_loop_prop() and woocommerce_product_loop_start()/ woocommerce_product_loop_end().

More detailed explanation is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/370913)